# Laravel root permission messed up

Tags: php, laravel-5, ubuntu-14.04

I have this Laravel project on my Ubuntu machine, and i accidentally gave chmod -R 777  to Ubuntu root. I did manage to cancel it, but it was to late. Now, like half of my root is green.

I have nothing useful on this machine except that Laravel project, and I have no problem with re-installing it. Is there a way to rebuild it? If not, when i backup my project, how to give it normal permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been through this before
Just run
**`sudo chmod 0644 -R *`** in your application's root directory
it will set the default permission level to **-rw-r--r--** (0644). As new laravel application comes with this permission level.

and you need to give `write` permission to storage folder and its files so run
**`sudo chmod 0755 storage`** and **`sudo chmod 0755 storage/* -R`**

You are good to go now. and for more about file and its permission level, I would recommend you to go through this https://askubuntu.com/questions/638796/what-is-meaning-of-755-permissions-in-samba-share it will help.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You described well everything i need to know.

Comment: I did this approach today. Reinstalled Ubuntu  + LAMP, but i get: "You don't have permission to access /projectName/public/ on this server." Could that be a server-side problem or?

Comment: yes, most probably with your server. Check your apache or nginx configuration and your .htaccess file too.

Answer (score 1):

When you reinstall the project it will gain the regular permissions. Remember that you only have to give 777 permissions to the "storage" folder.

And as far as I know, there is no way to set your Ubuntu files as they were before.

Answer (score 0):

Just change and update permissions of public/ folder inside your Laravel app/ folder to 0775, and then change permissions of files inside public_html/ folder to 0644. Also what is worth of noticing is user:group. What server and how do you run PHP handler?

Comment: Did the changes and i get: Warning: require(/var/www/html/projectl/public/../bootstrap/autoload.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/project/public/index.php on line 22  Im using Apache2, LAMP.